# terminal is asking for password

Tags: command-line

At some point I was asking about getting my machine to boot with the following commands:

```
hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/7ABB49654B799D40
hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/443AFBAD7FE50945
```

I made a script to be executed on startup, but I no longer require this as I made a small desktop config file to click on to accomplish the task. My problem is now, any time I try to use the Terminal, it first asks me for my password then after i type it in , it executes those commands.

I am not sure how this happened as I am not an advanced user. I simply want my terminal to run normally without executing those commands. I have looked in the startup folder, and the startup applications form the main menu and found nothing that looks like this.

Comment: Did you put these commands in `/home/user/.bashrc` or any other user configuration file?

Comment: yes @heemayl I think so at some point maybe, but i dont see that in that dir presently

Comment: Check other files: `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: found the entry in home folder (had to show hidden).. !  it works!

Comment: it should work..

Comment: Let me put that as as answer, select that as the answer to your question so that others can be notified that the problem is resolved.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put any command in `~/.bashrc` the command will be executed once you open up the terminal because the file (`~/.bashrc`) is sourced i.e. the commands inside it are automatically executed once you open up an interactive non-login `bash` instance. The solution is to find the commands in `~/.bashrc` and remove or comment out those.